# ImageMagick redraw svg image before convert

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick, png, imagemagick-convert

I have a script, which create svg diagram.

[image]

After creating I use ImageMagick to convert svg to image.

```
$image = new Imagick('image.svg');
$image->setImageFormat("png24");
$image->setCompression(imagick::COMPRESSION_UNDEFINED);
$image->setCompressionQuality(100);
//$image->resizeImage(1040, 854, imagick::FILTER_UNDEFINED, 1);
$image->writeImage('image.png');
$image->clear();
$image->destroy();
```

But when I convert svg, image have points in other places.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to provide the original SVG file so it can be tested against?

Comment: @KillerX Of course. In file or with XML code?

Comment: As a file is probably the best.

Comment: @KillerX http://iamlife.ru/wheels/koleso.svg

Comment: @KillerX There is array of points, which uses for creating SVG: [link](http://iamlife.ru/wheels/svg.js) But only with 9 and 10 strings the svg converts good

Comment: Might that be a timing issue, i. e. trying to read the file from disk for conversion before it has finished writing? - Why do you have 10 path definitions for 8 sectors?

Comment: @ccprog Hmmm... You mean I need to timeout some seconds before generate png image?

Comment: @ccprog There is 8 sectors and 10 variants of answer in each of sector

Comment: Not timeout, but make sure you are using a synchronuous write operation, or the read happens in a callback function after write finishes. Could you please post the answer to commandline `identify -list format | grep -i svg` and `identify -list delegate | grep -i svg` to find out which renderer is used by ImageMagick?

Comment: @ccprog Sorry, I don't know how to work with CLI in Virtual Hosting. I can give you ImageMagick version and Formats from phpinfo()

Comment: @ccprog The SVG file creates by `file_put_contents` function. There is no callback function of it.

Comment: I can't find any PHP interface to get at the delegate information, phpinfo() doesn't list it. `file_put_contents` is synchronuous, so that's not it. But the longer I think about it, the less I can imagine a situation where rendering errors could lead to the observed problems. I still guess its your SVG creation script. Can you share that?

Comment: @ccprog Script is [here](http://iamlife.ru/wheels/stack1.js). I remove all superfluous code.

Comment: And how does the server save it to file?

Comment: @ccprog
`$current = file_put_contents('koleso.svg','<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">'.$_POST['data'])`

Comment: Your svg file converts fine for me in Imagemagick 6.9.10.2 Q16 Mac OSX with the RSVG delegate in Imagemagick. Imagemagick can use 3 renderers: Inkscape, RSVG and its own internal MSVG/XML renderer in order of best to worst. You can use `convert -list format` to see what SVG renderer is being used. Use the latest of Inkscape or RSVG for best results.

Comment: @fmw42 I Understood with ssh, got data about formats. Please check [here](http://iamlife.ru/wheels/svg.jpg). As I understood right, I have RSVG renderer.

Comment: Yes, your Imagemagick does show RSVG installed. I get the correct result on my Mac OSX Sierra using Imagemagick 6.9.10.3 Q16 with RSVG 2.42.2 with this command: `convert koleso.svg koleso.png`. Your RSVG is rather old. Try upgrading it. What is your platform and version of Imagemagick. Perhaps it needs upgrading. But try either upgrading your RSVG or install Inkscape. Imagemagick will use that preferentially if found and on reasonably recent versions of Imagemagick. Before changing anything, does it work correctly in the command line?

Comment: CONTINUED: You would need Imagemagick 6.7.9-0 or higher to use Inkscape. But my guess is that you just need to upgrade RSVG

Comment: @fmw42 I have ImageMagick 6.7.2-7 2017-03-22 Q16 version. Try to convert with SSH, get the same image (with strange coords). Is it possible to update RSVG by myself from SSH?

Comment: You are likely on a Linux shared system from your IM version. It says 6.7.2.7 which by number is ancient. However, it was patched last on 3/22/17, which is over a year old. You should ask your hosting provider to see if there is a newer patch and apply it. Or ask them to upgrade RSVG. I do not think they will let you do any modifications yourself. You could find a provider that will install a current version in your private directory. Some hosting services will do that.

Comment: @fmw42 My hosting provider make updates by some graffic, not by request =( I have an opportunity to get VPS-server with root and make updates by myself. Is it some manuals to make updates with SSH?

Comment: I do not know about updating via SSH.

Comment: @fmw42 As a result I make a convert via svgToPng JS library. Good result after convert. Thanks a lot!